# Excel VBA insert character between number and letter

Tags: string, excel, vba

I would like some VBA code that would allow me to detect if a string contains any instances of a number followed by a letter and then insert a new character between them. For example:

User enters the following string:

```
4x^2+3x
```

Function returns:

```
4*x^2+3*x
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks for the advice guys, I think I have it working but I'd like to see if you can improve what I've got:

```
Sub insertStr()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim originalString As String
    Dim newLeft As String
    Dim newRight As String
    originalString = Cells(1, 1).Value
Repeat:
    For i = 1 To Len(originalString)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(originalString, i, 1)) = True Then
            Select Case Asc(Mid(originalString, i + 1, 1))
                Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
                    newLeft = Left(originalString, i)
                    newRight = Right(originalString, Len(originalString) - i)
                    originalString = newLeft & "*" & newRight
                    GoTo Repeat
                Case Else
                    GoTo Nexti
            End Select
        End If
Nexti:
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a code provider forum. Members here would help you to fix and improve your attempts. Consider writing your code and then ask for help.

Comment: Along the line of the previous comment by hawk, you could either iterate through the string, testing each character and the subsequent one; or you could use a regular expression with the replace method.

Comment: I'd go with RegEx. You'll have to learn to identify the correct pattern though. Some pattern may seem so simple, but if not well versed in RegEx, it will not be a walk in the park.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Ron's suggestion:

```
Public Function InsertStar(sIn As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, temp As String, CH As String
    L = Len(sIn)
    temp = Left(sIn, 1)
    For i = 2 To L
        CH = Mid(sIn, i, 1)
        If IsLetter(CH) And IsNumeric(Right(temp, 1)) Then
           temp = temp & "*"
        End If
        temp = temp & CH
    Next i
    InsertStar = temp
End Function

Public Function IsLetter(sIn As String) As Boolean
    If sIn Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then
        IsLetter = True
    Else
        IsLetter = False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

And just to show how it might be done using Regular expressions, and also allowing you to specify any particular character to insert:

```
Option Explicit
Function InsertChar(S As String, Insert As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(\d)(?=[A-Za-z])"
    InsertChar = .Replace(S, "$1" & Insert)
End With
End Function
```

The pattern is interpreted as

- **\d**   Find any number and capture it
- **(?=[A-Za-z])**  that is followed by a letter

And the replacement is

- **$1**  return the capturing group
- **&**   concatenated with
- **Insert**  (the string to be inserted)